# Batch file pass xml file contents to sqlplus

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, sqlplus

I have XML files that I want to upload into an Oracle DB through a Batch file process using sqlplus.
I am looping through my XML file like this:

```
for %%f in (%FILE%) do (
call :load_file %%f
)
```

%FILE% may be an issue as well, not 100% sure.  This variable is being set like:

```
set FILE=%CURRENT_DIRECTORY%\File1_*.xml
```

..And should be pulling any files that match the pattern.

In :load_file I need the actual file contents (as a string) to pass to sqlplus.  I have the following where %1 is the file name itself.  I actually need the XML file contents to be passed to my sqlplus command so the contents can actually be inserted into the Oracle DB.

```
:load_file
set FILECONTENTS=?    

sqlplus -S %DB_USER%/%DB_PASSWORD%@%DB_SID% @insert_xml_into_db.sql %1 %FILECONTENTS%
```

I may be looking/thinking about this wrong as well.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: That is not going to work.  You cannot do that.   See this for a proper solution - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb25loa.htm#ADXDB2900

Comment: That's sad.  Is there no way to at least read the file line by line into a batch variable, then pass that variable through sqlplus?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that reading in a XML file as a whole would be a good idea, but since you are also asking on how to read in lines from a file to an sql server. How about this example:

File (Dark.txt):

```
SELECT ('ABC') Row1 FROM Dual;
SELECT ('DEF') Row2 FROM Dual;
```

Batch script (Dark.bat):

```
@echo off

SET fileA=Dark.txt
SET USER=userName
SET PASSWORD=myPassword
SET DATABASE=myDatabase

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%fileA%) do (
    echo %%a | sqlplus %USER%/%PASSWORD%@%DATABASE%
)

pause
```

Comment: This is a good idea, however I really need to pass the whole file contents into a sqllite call, not line by line.  My comment above was about basically building script string variable up with the contents of the file line by line, then passing that whole variable into the sql call.  That does not seem possible either.